# xecjk conflict with ulem?

Tags: xecjk, ulem

Building the following MWE with xelatex in TeXnicCenter results in 5 errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

The \uline{論語 about 孔子}.

\end{document}
```

I give the first few lines of the log to show the versions I'm using:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.1.13)  19 JAN 2017 19:18 entering
>   extended mode
>   **./LaTeX1.tex (LaTeX1.tex LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3 Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 74 language(s) loaded.
>
> ....
>
> Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and
>   LuaLaTeX
>
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
>   Package: fontspec-xetex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX
>   and LuaLaTeX \l_fontspec_script_int=\count113
>   \l_fontspec_language_int=\count114 \l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count115
>   \l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134 \l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
>   \l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136

Here is error 1:

> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `normalem' for package`fontspec-xetex'.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> 281 \ProcessOptions*
>
> The option `normalem' was not declared in package`fontspec-xetex', perhaps you  misspelled its name. Try typing return to proceed.

Errors 2-5 comes in rapid succession:

> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cjk\CJKfntef.sty" Package:
>   CJKfntef 2015/04/18 4.8.4 \CJK@fntefSkip=\skip56 \CJK@nest=\count134
>   \CJK@fntefDimen=\dimen168 \CJK@underdotBox=\box48 \CJK@ULbox=\box49
>   \CJK@underanyskip=\dimen169 )
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.  \UL@hook 
>   l.44 ...to@hook \UL@hook { \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: }
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
>   was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I'
>   and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.  \UL@hook 
>   l.44 ...to@hook \UL@hook { \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: }
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
>   \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the
>   correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
>   forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.  \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: 
>   l.44 ...to@hook \UL@hook { \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: }
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
>   \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the
>   correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
>   forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! You can't use `end-group character }' after \the. 
>   \addto@hook #1#2->#1\expandafter {\the #1#2}
>
> l.44 ...to@hook \UL@hook { \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: }
>
> I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.44 ...to@hook \UL@hook { \xeCJK_hook_for_ulem: }
>
> You're in trouble here.  Try typing    to proceed. If that doesn't
>   work, type  X return  to quit.

There is a PDF output.  The line of text is fine, but there is a '0' on a line by itself before:

[image]

Any idea what's gone wrong?

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me. Perhaps try updating your packages?

Comment: I just updated my MikTeX installation.  You can see from the log:

Comment: Sorry, I got locked out before finishing the comment. I updated my MikTeX installation a week ago.  You can see from the log that the xelatex format was created on Jan 13: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.1.13) The xecjk.sty is dated 1/2/2017, and xecjk.pdf says it's v. 3.4.5, the latest according to CTAN

Comment: I've just updated all my packages again, but your MWE still compiles fine for me.

Comment: It's very strange; I uninstalled MikTeX and reinstalled it, but I still get the error.

Comment: Seems that there is no need to use `fontspec` package.